# Problem when i try to get the value of a function in Flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-polymer

Hi i cant not get the value of de value that return my function postTest()

```
                           String usuario = usernameController.text;
                                  print('Si $usuario');
                                  String password = passwordController.text;
                                  print('Password: $password');

                                  print("${postTest(usuario, password)}");
                                }
                              },
                            ),
                            Registrate(),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 500, left: 170),
                child: ImagenAmbulancia(),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  postTest(usuario, password) async {
    final uri = 'http://10.0.2.2:5000/base/';

    http.Response response = await http
        .post(Uri.parse(uri), body: {"User": usuario, "Pass": password});
    var repuesta = response.body;
    String estadoUsuario = jsonDecode(repuesta)["respuesta"];
    return estadoUsuario;
  }
}
```

i try to save the value that get me postTest but i cant ... return me Future , but i want the string

Comment: As is an async function you need to wait the result before use it, call the method using await

Comment: @JorgeVieira but when i try Print inside to the function postTest like print("$estadoUsuario") i get the value ... but when i try to call the function like String Value= postTest(usuario,password) y cant get the value that return estadoUsuario

Answer (score 1):

when you want to use your method, because its future type (and will be fill in future) you should use `.then` when you call your method like this

```
postTest(usuario, password).then((value) {
 print(value);
});
```